# onclick and onclientclick

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the following line in asp.net

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="createuser" 
    OnClientClick="javascript:$('#dialogform').dialog('open');" 
    onclick="AddCaseInfo_Click">Create Case</asp:LinkButton>
```

onclientclick works fine, but not onclick. I tried

```
OnClientClick="javascript:$('#dialogform').dialog('open');return true;"
```

or

```
OnClientClick="javascript: return $('#dialogform').dialog('open');"
```

...but it still doesnt work.

:(  Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to specify `javascript:` or `return true`:

```
OnClientClick="$('#dialogform').dialog('open');"
```